# Объединение ячеек в столбце и удаление лишних строк

Tags: sql, ssms

Из источника данных excel получена таблица (как пример)

| номер п/п | идентификатор | наименование |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | F001 | стул черный |
| 2 | E003 | стол зеленый |
| 3 | T027 | стул |
| null | null | null |
| null | null | красный |
| null | null | null |
| 4 | E508 | стол синий |

Т.е. ячейка 3 строки 3 разделилась на четыре. И таких строчек много.

Можно ли как то объединять строки и удалить лишние в sql? Или проше поправить данные в excel?

Comment: *Т.е. ячейка 3 строки 3 разделилась на четыре.* ??? Это ж не Excel, тут ячеек нет. Есть "строка N" и "поле XXX".

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Данные никак не позволяют установить порядок друг относительно друга и определить, что к чему относится. То, что ты видишь строки на экране в каком-то порядке - это несуществующая фикция, и невозможно определить что, скажем, "строка 5 относится к строке 3". Так что править надо в источнике, в Excel-файле. Либо надо импортировать с дополнительным полем, в которое будет записываться номер строки-источника - тогда задача действительно решается на стороне SQL.